# Django ORM get return value of model-class method in values()-modified QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm programming a farming game to learn Django. 
For one of my views, I would like both the fields of an Object, as well as the result value of one of its methods. Preferrably in the same collection. `

Now, I can call the method for any object in a QuerySet.  However, I want an extra field for the time a plant has been in the ground. Something like this:

```
plants = Planted.objects.filter(farm=farm).values('crop', 'date_planted')
for plant in planted:
  plant['time_planted'] = int((now - plant['date_planted']).total_seconds())
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Planted(models.Model):
    farm = models.ForeignKey(Farm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    crop = models.ForeignKey(Crop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    date_planted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # ...

    def can_be_harvested(self):
        # Returns boolean value
```

I've tried including it in a QuerySet as an [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)-value. My attempts failed and Django's documentation mentions possible deprecation on this modifier, so this is most likely not the way to achieve what I want.

I can only add the time_planted-key if I query for certain [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), effectively converting my Planted objects into dictionaries. But I can't seem to add the result of can_be_harvested in my QuerySet.

What is the best way to provide the fields, the result of the Model-method and the 'time_planted' to my template so that I can loop over all these fields with just one for-loop?

Comment: What does `can_be_harvested` do? Can you fill that method for us to understand?

Comment: To my knowledge this isn't possible, since the ORM is only concerned with SQL queries. You might want to look at aggregations / annotations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation and see if your `can_be_harvested` value can be expressed through ORM queries that way that way

Comment: @OzgurVatansever  `can_be_harvested` returns a boolean. The method itself works, and I can get to the return values while the QuerySet is filled with Planted-objects. But I modify my QuerySet with values(). I have had to update my question since I left that bit out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want here. A queryset is a collection of model instances; each of those instances has access to the `can_be_harvested` method which can be called whenever you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and clarify my intentions.

Answer (score 0):

After a triple facepalm, I realised I can also add the time_planted as a method to my Planted model, just like `can_be_harvested`. That way my QuerySet of Planted objects provides all information I need.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

#...

def time_planted(self):
    now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    return int((now - self.date_planted).total_seconds())
```

Derp.